# Run command with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, cmd, command

I want to make a script that which if I open it on my machine (as administrator), it run a command on different machines (without entering credentials). 
I used to make a script that restarts services. I did it like this:

```
$out = "lokation\output_NoService.txt"
Clear-Content $out

$data = Get-Content "lokation\input_PCs.txt"

foreach ($line in $data) {
    $computer = $line.Split(":")[0]
    $ServiceName = $line.Split(":")[1]

    if ($sObj = Get-Service-COmputerName $Computer -Name $ServiceName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
        Restart-Service -InputObj $sObj
        Write-Host "Restarting $ServiceName on $computer"
    } else {
        Write-Host "$ServiceName is not running on $computer"
        Add-Content $out "$computer;$ServiceName"
    }
}
```

`input_PCs.txt` contained the machine names and the name of the service to be restarted.
eg: `PCName:Servicename`

This is how I want to scan PCs from a txt and run command on the machines that are in txt.

For example, such a command.

run example.exe + paramters from c drive. 
Ergo: `C:\example.exe -paramaters`

Comment: For me it looks like it should work as intended... What is your problem?

Comment: in addition to other things, you need to add a space before the 2nd hyphen in >>> `Get-Service-COmputerName` <<<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this ?

```
foreach($line in $data) {

    $computer = $line.split(":")[0]   

    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock {C:\example.exe -parameters}

}
```

In order for this to work, example.exe will need to be present on your remote computers.  If this isn't the case yet, before the above, you can add something like this

```
if (!(Test-Path -Path "\\$computer\c$\example.exe")) {

    Copy-Item -Path "X:\path_to_file\example.exe" -Destination "\\$computer\c$" -Force

}
```

And if you don't want it to request any credentials, make sure your Powershell session is started under your admin user that has access to all the computers' c-drives.

Answer (score 2):

The [Restart-Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/restart-service) does not have a `-ComputerName` parameter to manage services on remote machines. To use that cmdlet remotely, you can use

```
Invoke-Command -Computername $computer -ArgumentList $ServiceName -ScriptBlock { 
    param($service)
    Restart-Service -Name $service}
```

---

**Edit**

---

[Lee_Daily](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080908/lee-dailey) pointed out that the object returned from `Get-Service` contains a `MachineName` property. When this object is used in a following `Restart-Service` as `InputObject` parameter, the cmdlet uses that MachineName property to restart the service on that remote machine.

As I have never thought of that, I've been testing with it and indeed it does work that way.

Your code (with corrected ComputerName parameter) should therefore work as intended, provided you have permissions on the remote computers to do so:

```
$out = "lokation\output_NoService.txt"
Clear-Content $out

$data = Get-Content "lokation\input_PCs.txt"

foreach ($line in $data) {
    $computer, $serviceName = $line -split ':', 2

    if ($sObj = Get-Service -ComputerName $computer -Name $serviceName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
        Restart-Service -InputObj $sObj
        Write-Host "Restarting $serviceName on $computer"
    } 
    else {
        Write-Host "Service '$serviceName' cannot be found on computer '$computer'"
        Add-Content -Path $out -Value "$computer; $serviceName"
    }
}
```

This however does not let you add user credentials because `Get-Service` does not provide a `Credentials` object.
If you need to use different credentials, you can do like below:

```
$credential = Get-Credential
$out = "lokation\output_NoService.txt"
Clear-Content $out

$data = Get-Content "lokation\input_PCs.txt"

# unravel the $credential object into plain username and password:
$user     = $credential.GetNetworkCredential().UserName
$password = $credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password

foreach ($line in $data) {
    $computer, $serviceName = $line -split ':', 2
    # create a connection to the remote machine using credentials
    net use "\\$computer\c$" $password /USER:$user

    if ($sObj = Get-Service -ComputerName $computer -Name $serviceName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
        Restart-Service -InputObj $sObj
        Write-Host "Restarting $serviceName on $computer"
    } 
    else {
        Write-Host "Service '$serviceName' cannot be found on computer '$computer'"
        Add-Content -Path $out -Value "$computer; $serviceName"
    }
}
```

The last option I can think of is to use the `Get-WmiObject` cmdlet which for convenience I've wrapped in a custom function:

```
function Restart-RemoteService {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
       [Parameter(Position = 0,Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true,ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
       [string]$ComputerName, 

       [Parameter(Position = 1,Mandatory = $true)]
       [string]$ServiceName,

       [Parameter(Position = 2,Mandatory = $true)]
       [string]$ErrorFile

       [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
       [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$Credential
    )

    $wmiParams = @{
        'Class'        = 'Win32_Service'
        'ComputerName' = $ComputerName
        'Filter'       = "Name='$ServiceName'"
    }
    if ($Credential) { $wmiParams['Credential'] = $Credential }

    $svc = Get-WmiObject @wmiParams
    if (!$svc) {
        Write-Warning "Service '$ServiceName' cannot be found on computer '$ComputerName'"
        Add-Content -Path "lokation\output_NoService.txt" -Value "$ComputerName; $ServiceName"
    }
    if ($svc.State -eq 'Running') {
        Write-Verbose "Stopping service '$ServiceName' on computer '$ComputerName'"
        [void]$svc.StopService()
        $maxWait = 20
        do {
            Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100
            $maxWait--
            if ($maxWait -le 0) {
                Throw "Could not stop service '$ServiceName'"
            }
        } while (( Get-WmiObject @wmiParams).State -ne 'Stopped')

    }
    Write-Verbose "Starting service '$ServiceName' on computer '$ComputerName'"
    [void]$svc.StartService()
}
```

Your code could then look like this:

```
$out = "lokation\output_NoService.txt"
Clear-Content $out

$data = Get-Content "lokation\input_PCs.txt"

foreach ($line in $data) {
    $computer, $serviceName = $line -split ':', 2

    # if needed, you can pass Credentials too
    Restart-RemoteService -ComputerName $computer -ServiceName $serviceName -ErrorFile $out -Verbose
}
```

Comment: i THINK that the object from the previous `Get-Service` call will have a `.MachineName` property and that means the `-InputObject` parameter will use that to reach out to remote systems. i cannot test that [only one system], but i recall seeing `Get-Service` piped to`Restart-Service` when used against remote systems in posts on the subject.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Interesting! I must admit that never crossed my mind.. I'm on mobile now so cannot test.

Comment: i look forward to seeing your results ... [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey It took some doing to test this out, but you're right, the `MachineName` property is used by the `Restart-Service` cmdlet if the returned object from `Get-Service` is provided through parameter `-InputObject`. While playing around with this I have also added a method using `Get-WmiObject`. Thanks!

Comment: neato! [*grin*] if you are going for completeness, you can also use `Invoke-Command`, or `New-PSSession` with `Enter-PSSession` ... but that is getting into writing a full tutorial ...